# (Anti)commutators at different times

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, commutator, causality, anticommutator

Why does the **commutator** of two operators evaluated at different times vanish? Take for instance a fermonic field $\psi_\sigma (\vec{x},t)$,  which satisfies the well known anti-commutation relations at equal times

\begin{equation}
[\psi_\sigma (\vec{x},t),\psi^\dagger_{\sigma'} (\vec{x}',t)]_+ = \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}') \, \delta_{\sigma \sigma'} 
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is a flavour index.

Is that correct to state that the commutator at different times vanishes? In other words
\begin{equation}
[\psi_\sigma (\vec{x},t),\psi_{\sigma} (\vec{x},t')]_- = 0\quad ?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

No. (Anti)commutators do not necessarily  vanish at different times.  In order to compute the (anti)commutator at different times you have to solve the dynamics of the system with $\psi(x,t)\to e^{iHt}\psi(x,0) e^{-iHt}$.  What is  true in a relativistic field theory, with Bose (Fermi) fields satisfying the spin-statistics relation however, is that the  (anti)commutator will vanish if $x$ and $x'$ are *spacelike* separated, so that  $(x-x')^2<0$ in the $(+,-,-,\ldots)$ metric. This ensures that no signals can travel faster than light.